# Почему не выводит ошибку регистрации php

Tags: php, ajax

Не пишет ошибку что логин занят и что поля пустые, всегда пишет что успешно зарегистрированы . В базу заносит если верно данные вести. 
Файл reg.php

```
 <?php
 include("include/db_connect.php"); 
 include("functions/functions.php"); 
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <link rel="stylesheet"         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>Регистрация</title>


 </head>

  <body>
<div id="block-body">
  <?php
    include("include/block-header.php");  
  ?>
        <div id="block-cont">
 <form method="post" id="form_reg" action="/reg/handler_reg.php">
 <p id="reg_message"></p>
 <div id="block-form-reg">
  <div class="form-group">
<label for="inputName">Логин</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reg_login" id="reg_login"       placeholder="Введите Логин" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputPass">Пароль</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass"         placeholder="Введите Пароль" />
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="reg_email" id="reg_email"  placeholder="Введите Email" />
   </div>

    <input type="submit"  name="reg_submit" id="reg_submit" value="Регистраиця" />



    </div>
  </form>
   </div>
        <?php
          include("include/block-footer.php");
        ?>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shop-script.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
     <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $("#form_reg").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // прерываем отправку формы
    var data = $('#form_reg').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"/reg/handler_reg.php",
        data:data,
        error:function(){
                            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#reg_message").html('Загрузка...');
        },
        success: function(html){
            $("#block-form-reg").fadeOut(300);
            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
        }

    });

    return false;
   });

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Файл handler_reg.php

```
 session_start();
include("../include/db_connect.php");
  include("../functions/functions.php");

$error = array();

   $login = iconv("UTF-8",     "cp1251",strtolower(clear_string($_POST['reg_login']))); 
   $pass = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",strtolower(clear_string($_POST['reg_pass']))); 

   $email = iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251",clear_string($_POST['reg_email'])); 



  if (strlen($login) < 5 or strlen($login) > 15)
 {
  $error[] = "Логин должен быть от 5 до 15 символов!"; 
 }
  else
 {   
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM reg_user WHERE login = '$login'",$link);
  If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
  $error[] = "Логин занят!";
 }

  }

   if (strlen($pass) < 7 or strlen($pass) > 15) $error[] = "Укажите пароль от 7 до 15 символов!";
 if (!preg_match("/^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_.]?[a-z0-9]+)?@[a-z0-9_.-]+(?:\.?[a-z0-9]+)?\.[a-z]{2,5})$/i",trim($email))) $error[] = "Укажите корректный email!";



 if (count($error))
  {

echo implode('<br />',$error);

  }else
  {   
   $pass   = md5($pass);
   $pass   = strrev($pass);
   $pass   = "9nm2rv8q".$pass."2yo6z";

     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

mysql_query("   INSERT INTO reg_user(login,pass,email)
 VALUES( '".$login."','".$pass."','".$email."')",$link);

 echo 'Регистрация прошла успешно! <a href="index.php">Перейти на главную   страницу.</a> ';
  }        



 ?>
```

Comment: `handler_reg.php` где?

Comment: Ой извиняюсь, добавил

Comment: `if (count($error))` - что вы здесь проверяете?

Comment: количество элементов в массиве $error

Comment: ок, если в масиве нет елементов что вернет?

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать:

```
if (count($error)>0) //если в масиве есть елементы
  {

echo implode('<br />',$error);

}else
{   
 $pass   = md5($pass);
 $pass   = strrev($pass);
 $pass   = "9nm2rv8q".$pass."2yo6z";

 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$addDB = mysql_query("   INSERT INTO reg_user(login,pass,email)
 VALUES( '".$login."','".$pass."','".$email."')",$link);

 if($addDB) // если переменная $addDB существует то запрос к базе выполнен
{echo 'Регистрация прошла успешно! <a href="index.php">Перейти на главную   страницу.</a> ';}
else {
echo 'Запись не внесена в базу';}
  }
```

Comment: все равно выводит сообщение что успешно зарегистрировались

Comment: в ajax проблема мне кажется, но у меня не хватает знаний чтобы понять

Comment: попробуйте вместо `$("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!"); ` прописать `$("#reg_message").addClass("reg_mess_good").fadeIn(400).html(html);` Должно выводить сообщение полученое с handler_reg.php

Comment: кого вы годаете Дмитрий когда error срабатывает в ajax?

Comment: Dmitriy Kondratiuk, спасибо большое, помогло, стал выводить ошибки из handler_reg

Answer (score 0):

Это

```
 if (count($error))
 {
    echo implode('<br />',$error);
 }
```

меняем на это:

```
 if (count($error))
 {
   http_response_code(409);
   echo implode('<br />',$error);
 }
```

но тут вам стоит делаить как все возвращать json с флагом ошибки либо правильности.

p.s. Не буду удалять так как в ajax callback error срабатывает ели была возвращен код ошибки http.

Comment: заменил выдал ошибку Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code()

Comment: @Artemfomkin `header("HTTP/1.0 409 Conflict");` можно этой заменить у вас php 5.3 видимо какой то

Comment: да у меня php 5.3, теперь при нажатие регистрация сверху появляется reg_login=®_pass=®_email=®_captcha=

Comment: @Artemfomkin что то не пойму вроде ответ выше вам подошол?

Comment: хотел ваш метод посмотреть

Comment: @Artemfomkin тот ответ более проще в том смысле что не надо заморачиваться с ответом сервера.